# Tradução na mensagem a agradecer a revisão das edições sugeridas

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

Após atingir o limite diário para revisões, aparece uma mensagem a agradecer e a indicar o tempo que falta até poder efetuar mais:

[image: Captura de tela]

A mensagem está parcialmente traduzida, muito embora me pareça que o conteúdo traduzido é "injetado" na mensagem que parece ser a mesma para as várias tarefas de revisão.

**Sugiro a seguinte tradução:**

> Obrigado pela analise de XXX hoje; volte XXX para continuar a analisar.

**Ficando o seguinte exemplo prático:**

Obrigado pela analise de 20 Edições sugeridas hoje; volte em 3 horas para continuar a analisar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essas expressões já foram *internacionalizadas*, mas ainda não foram traduzidas, pelo que o sistema usa a versão em Inglês. Nós normalmente temos uma "entrega" de expressões traduzidas a cada duas semanas, de modo que o problema vai desaparecer em breve.

---

> Those sentences have now been localized, but have not been translated yet so the system uses the English version. We usually have a "drop" of translated strings every couple of weeks, so the problem will go away shortly.